# Binary Tree getParent Function

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I have implemented this function that searches recursively from a node and returns a node that has a child with some given node data, if found, 0 otherwise.

```
Node<T> * BinaryTree<T>::searchParent ( T key , Node<T> * p ) const
{
    if ( p == 0 )
        return 0;

    if ( p->left && p->left->info == key )
        return p;
    else if ( p->right && p->right->info == key  )
        return p;

    Node<T> * q = searchParent ( key , p->left );

    if ( q == 0 )
        return searchParent ( key , p->right );

    return q;
}
```

Now I want to implement this function that finds and returns the data of the parent of a given node, if only the node data is given.

```
T BinaryTree<T>::getParent( T node )
```

But I am not able to implement this recursively or non recursively.

Comment: What does this function do?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Edited. Though OP should've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea:

```
T BinaryTree<T>::getParent(T node)
{
  return searchParent(node, root)->info;
}
```

You may have to add some error-checking. Since you're returning a generic type, you may be left with having to throw an exception if not found or if already at the root.